# New ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net

When creating a new web project in ASP.NET  are you better off to use the "ASP.NET empty web application" or the "asp.net web forms application"

Comment: ASP.NET empty web application, so I don't have to delete anything :D

Comment: What are you trying to do? It depends on what you want.

Comment: Right now I am trying to get a basic understanding of web development with ASP.NET. I have an idea for a site that eventually I will turn into a working web site but right now just using it to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend *against* even bothering with ASP.Net Web Forms. It was an interesting idea that proved to be unweildy in practical applications. The entire web development industry is moving towards some kind of MVC framework or another whether you're using PHP, Ruby or ASP.Net so you're best off using that.

Of course there are still a lot of ASP.Net Web Forms applications out there and they're likely to exist for some time into the future so there is some benefit to learning the technology but I would avoid it for any new projects.

As per your question if you should use the empty project or not it doesn't really make a difference. If you're just starting out the populated project can give you a basic idea of how the structure works but if you're comfortable enough building it from scratch then go with the empty project.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you want to do.

Generally speaking, there are three kinds of ASP.NET application project:

- Web Forms - what ASP.NET was originally back in 2001. Its use is discouraged in modern and greenfield applications because it is built-around outdated ideas about how web applications should work.
- MVC - The new hotness. Try to use this. StackOverflow is built using this.
- Everything else - too many to list, but this generally requires you create an empty project and do everything from scratch using `IHttpHandler`.

If you're new to ASP.NET I strongly recommend avoiding the two project types you listed as they're both for Web Forms; consider using the "ASP.NET MVC Application" options instead - if you're using VS2008 then you need to download and install the ASP.NET MVC 2 add-on. VS2010 and later come with the MVC templates preinstalled.

You might want to use the Empty Web Application project template if you want to work from scratch using `IHttpHandler`, but you sound new to this, so I recommend avoiding it.